# how to use plotly to plot interactive data like stacked bar?

Tags: stack, plotly, pandas-groupby

I have plot an interactive ploting using plotly library with using groupby.

i want to convert this ploting from multiple bars into stacked bar .

```
df.groupby(['event_type','groups']).size().unstack().iplot(kind='bar', bins=20, theme="white", title="Event type over groups",xTitle='event type', yTitle='Number of person')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer just add **barmode='stack'**