# How can plot categorical stacked bar over periodic time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to extract a stacked bar chart over **periodic** time (5 years):

```
import pandas as pd
categorical = ["RL","CD(others)","DL","ML","ML","ML","DL","ML","DL","DL"]
year = [2014,2014,2015,2015,2016,2017,2019,2021,2022,2022]
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':year,
                   'keywords':categorical})
df
```

I tried relevant [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558644/clustered-stacked-bar-plot-over-time-python), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63612273/how-to-use-plotly-to-plot-interactive-data-like-stacked-bar), [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63014596/combining-two-stacked-bar-plots-for-a-grouped-stacked-bar-plot) to resolve the problem:

```
#solution1:Pivot table
df.pivot_table(index='year',
               columns='keywords',
              # values='paper_count',
               aggfunc='sum')
#df.plot(x='year', y='paper_count', kind='bar')


#solution2: groupby
# reset_index() gives a column for counting after groupby uses year and category
ctdf = (df.reset_index()
          .groupby(['year'], as_index=False)
          .count()
          # rename isn't strictly necessary here; it's just for readability
          .rename(columns={'index':'paper_count'})
       )
ctdf.plot(x='year', y='paper_count', kind='bar')
```

At the end, I couldn't figure out how can plot this periodically by counting every 5 yrs:

`2000-2005`, `2005-2010`, `2015-2020`, `2020-2025`.

**expected output**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the full logic if the provided example is supposed to match the data, but you can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to form bins, then [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to get the cumulated sum (remove this if you just want a simple sum):

```
years = list(range(2000, 2030, 5))
# [2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025]
labels = [f'{a}-{b}' for a,b in zip(years, years[1:])]
# ['2000-2005', '2005-2010', '2010-2015', '2015-2020', '2020-2025']

(df.assign(year=pd.cut(df['year'], bins=years, labels=labels))
   .groupby(['year', 'keywords'])['year'].count()
   .unstack()
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

With the red line:

```
years = list(range(2000, 2030, 5))
# [2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025]
labels = [f'{a}-{b}' for a,b in zip(years, years[1:])]
# ['2000-2005', '2005-2010', '2010-2015', '2015-2020', '2020-2025']

df2 = (df
 .assign(year=pd.cut(df['year'], bins=years, labels=labels))
 .groupby(['year', 'keywords'])['year'].count()
 .unstack()
)

ax = df2.plot.bar(stacked=True)
# adding arbitrary shift (0.1)
df2.sum(axis=1).add(0.1).plot(ax=ax, color='red', marker='s', label='paper count')
ax.legend()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I think that solved the periodic stacked bar problem, and I just commented `.cumsum()`. Would you mind If I ask to add the red lineplot and involved `.cumsum()` for that to complete the answer?

Comment: Check the update, assuming the line is the sum

Comment: Apart from a bit shifting redline, can't we reflect the red line label so-called "paper_count" in legend?

Comment: You can do whatever you want ;)